# How to format result from csv file to look more like a table

Tags: python, csv, format, tabular

How to format output into a table similar to below design while leaving out the unnecessary columns?  I am working on the def two and it gives back the raw data I want but I dont know how to format it to resemble the table below it.

```
['1000.3', '', '']
['Coke Can', '1.1', '100']
['Bread', '0.7', '30']
['Spaghetti', '1.2', '100']
['Tomato Sauce', '0.8', '100']
['Bin Bags', '2.5', '4']
Enter anything to return to main menu


-----------------------------
Shop has 1000.30 in cash
-----------------------------
| Product             |  Qty |
-----------------------------
| Coke Can            | 00100|
|----------------------------|
| Bread               | 00030|
|----------------------------|
| Spaghetti           | 00100|
|----------------------------|
| Tomato Sauce        | 00100|
|----------------------------|
| Bin Bags            | 00004|
|----------------------------|


 

def two():
    with open('../stock.csv') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        first_row = next(readCSV)
        print(first_row)
        for row in readCSV:
            print(row)
    anykey=input("Enter anything to return to main menu")
    mainMenu()   

#main routine
mainMenu()
```

Comment: You can use pandas instead of writing a function. Writing a function would be more time consuming. But for that you need to make a little change in your csv file if you want your table to look like you have shown in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By just playing around a little with the print statement, you should be able to achieve this with ease.

```
import csv
fields = [] 
filename = "stock.csv"
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
    fields = next(csvreader)
    print('-'*40)
    print(f'Shop has {fields[0]} in cash')
    print('-'*40)
    for row in csvreader:
        print('-'*40)
        print('| ', row[0], ' '*(24-len(row[0])),'| ', row[2],' '*2, '|')
        print('-'*40)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. What I really want to do though is for the csv file to read in the information without me hard coding in the values and producing it in a tabular form to mirror the table above.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much.